# Assign ranking from tuples of scores in list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples, enumerate

I’ve got three tuples in a list, if I’m correct, and I’m trying to return the ranking of the three best player of a given game. Considering the following:

```
players_score  = [ ('Joe', 100, 34, 38, 90, 67, 3, 10),
                   ('Bob', 90, 38, 4, 100, 60, 4, 11),
                   ('May', 80, 36, 40, 91, 70, 2, 12),
                   ('Anna', 95, 32, 36, 92, 68, 8, 13) ]
```

Printing the results of game one returns the following score:

```
[('Joe', 100), ('Bob', 90), ('May', 80), ('Anna', 95)]
```

But instead, I would like to have the program print this:

```
[ ('Joe', 1), ('Anna', 2), ('Bob', 3) ]
```

Since Joe has 100 points, Anna has 95 and Bob has 90.

I'm thinking about using `enumerate()`, but I figured I may be better of by first converting the tuples to a dictionary, which I tried in the last part of my code, but without much luck.
I started trying the following:

```
#prints the corresponding score with the player.
game = int(input("Please enter the number of a game: "))
game_score = [ (p[0], p[game]) for p in players_score]
print(game_score)

#prints a list of results ordered from high to low.
score_list = []

for p in players_score:
    score_list.append(p[game])

score_list.sort(reverse=True)
print(score_list)

#prints only the name and the result of the first game
list = [ (name, first) for name, first, second, third, fourth, sixth, seventh, eighth in players_score ]
print(list)

#trying to get a convert from a tuple to a dict.
for name, first, second, third, forth, sixth, seventh, eighth in players_score:
    dict(name, first)

print(dict)
```

Comment: "return the ranking of the three best player": recommend you use a `heapq` (see [`heapq.nlargest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest)) rather than doing a full sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this:

```
a = [('Joe', 100), ('Bob', 90), ('May', 80), ('Anna', 95)]
```

Try to sort this with the second parameter of each tuple:

```
a = sorted(a, key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)
```

then:

```
result = [(v[0], i+1) for i,v in enumerate(a)][0:3]
```

the output will be:

```
[('Joe', 1), ('Anna', 2), ('Bob', 3)]
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition for the first answer, you can convert the player scores to dictionary, to ease manipulation afterwards:

For example:

```
players_score  = [ ('Joe', 100, 34, 38, 90, 67, 3, 10),
                   ('Bob', 90, 38, 4, 100, 60, 4, 11),
                   ('May', 80, 36, 40, 91, 70, 2, 12),
                   ('Anna', 95, 32, 36, 92, 68, 8, 13) ]

# convert player's scores to dictionary
games = {}
for (player_name, *scores) in players_score:
    for game_no, score in enumerate(scores, 1):
        games.setdefault(game_no, {}).setdefault(player_name, {})
        games[game_no][player_name] = score

# the dictionary "games" will look like:

# {1: {'Anna': 95, 'Bob': 90, 'Joe': 100, 'May': 80},
#  2: {'Anna': 32, 'Bob': 38, 'Joe': 34, 'May': 36},
#  3: {'Anna': 36, 'Bob': 4, 'Joe': 38, 'May': 40},
#  4: {'Anna': 92, 'Bob': 100, 'Joe': 90, 'May': 91},
#  5: {'Anna': 68, 'Bob': 60, 'Joe': 67, 'May': 70},
#  6: {'Anna': 8, 'Bob': 4, 'Joe': 3, 'May': 2},
#  7: {'Anna': 13, 'Bob': 11, 'Joe': 10, 'May': 12}}

game = int(input("Please enter the number of a game: "))

# now print the first three names from the game:

for place, (name, score) in enumerate( sorted(games[game].items(), key=lambda k: k[1], reverse=True)[:3], 1 ): # <-- only first three places
    print('{}. {:<10} {}'.format(place, name, score))
```

Prints:

```
Please enter the number of a game: 4
1. Bob        100
2. Anna       92
3. May        91
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```py
import numpy as np

players_score  =np.array([ ('Joe', 100, 34, 38, 90, 67, 3, 10),
                   ('Bob', 90, 38, 4, 100, 60, 4, 11),
                   ('May', 80, 36, 40, 91, 70, 2, 12),
                   ('Anna', 95, 32, 36, 92, 68, 8, 13) ])

players_rank=list(
   map(lambda x: (players_score[x[0], 0], *x[1]+1), 
      enumerate(players_score[:, 1:].argsort(axis=0))
   )
)
```

Output:

```py
[
   ('Joe', 1, 4, 4, 2, 2, 3, 1), 
   ('Bob', 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2), 
   ('May', 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3), 
   ('Anna', 4, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4)
]
```